# Malloc for structures

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am not getting the correct output here, 
The code takes the no of inputs and option as an input, then takes the name of student year and gender and based on option provided gives the output. The output can be the name appearing first in the dictionary or the smaller value of the year  amongst the inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student_record
{
    int passing_year;
    char gender;
    char name[20];
};

typedef struct student_record student;

student* find_specific(student* find, int option_num, int number)
{
    int i;
    student* temp = find;
    int opt = option_num;
    int num = number;

    if(opt==1)
    {
        for(i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            if( strcmp(temp->name, find[i].name) >0)
                temp = find+i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<num; i++)
                {
                    if (temp->passing_year > find[i].passing_year)
                        temp = find+i;
                }
    }

    return temp;

}

int main() {

    student* example;
    student* final;

    int i;
    int option_num, number_of_students;
    printf("Enter 2the number of students, option number");
    scanf("%d" "%d", &number_of_students, &option_num);

    example = (student* )malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(student));

    printf("Enter the name, passing year and gender");
    for(i=0; i< number_of_students; i++)
    {

        scanf("%s" "%d" "%c", example[i].name, &example[i].passing_year, &example[i].gender);
    }

    final = find_specific(example, option_num, number_of_students);

    printf("%s" "%d" "%c", final->name, final->passing_year, final->gender );





    return 0;
}
```

i am getting a segmentation fault. I can't figure out exactly where am I screwing up.

Comment: "I can't figure out exactly where am I screwing up." - always run under a debugger when you're unsure what is going on, and it'll tell you.

Comment: Please can you provide some sample input?

Comment: I like how number is assigned to num just for the purpose of being used in the for loop...

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) but, check that it's not `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scanf()` and `printf()` format strings are probably wrong.

```
scanf("%s" "%d" "%c", example[i].name, &example[i].passing_year, &example[i].gender);
```

should probably be

```
scanf("%s %d %c", example[i].name, &example[i].passing_year, &example[i].gender);
```

(without the extra quotes).  The compiler will concatenate adjacent
string literals, so instead of a compiler error, it interpreted your format string as equivalent to `"%s%d%c"` (without whitespace in between).
That probably doesn't match the layout of your input, so some of the values were probably left uninitialized in a way that caused problems later.

You should always check the return value of `scanf` and similar library functions,
to ensure that you got the input format you told the compiler to expect.

Comment: The problem is that the `"%c"` specifier is matching the whitespace, to skip it you need to have a explicit whitespace before the `"%c"` specifier, hence `"%s%d %c"`.